# How to do I add new column after endling of loop inside Gridview?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-gridview

I want to add a new column after the end of the loop inside Gridview.
Right now in my code I add the append functionality in floatingActionButton but I want to add this append functionality in the column after every end of the column loop.

Like this:-  need to add a new column after end of loop

[image]

Please see this image for a better understanding.

I hope you understand what I want to say.

Right now my output is like this:-  see there is floatingActionButton where i add append functionality to add a new column

[image]

Here is my code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/utils/widget_functions.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/custom/BorderIcon.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/screens/Relation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(new MaterialApp(
  home: new Photos(),
));
}

class Photos extends StatefulWidget {
 var usrid;

 Photos({Key? key, @required this.usrid}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _Photos createState() => _Photos();
}

class _Photos extends State<Photos>{

int counter = 0;
//List<Widget> _list = List<Widget>();
List<Widget> _list = <Widget> [];


@override
 void initState() {

 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   Widget child = _newItem(i);
   _list.add(child);
 };
}

void on_Clicked() {
 Widget child = _newItem(counter);
 setState(
      () => _list.add(child),
 );
}

Widget _newItem(int i) {
 Key key = new Key('item_${i}');
 Column child = Column(
    key: key,
    children: [
      Stack(
          children:  [
            Card(
              elevation: 0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xffa1a1a1),
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
              ),
              child: SizedBox(
                //width: 300,
                height: 100,
                child: Center(child:
                Icon(
                  Icons.image,
                  color: Color(0xffcccccc),
                  size: 60,
                ),

                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 9,
              right: 9,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () => _removeItem(i),
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  width: 20,
                  'assets/images/close.svg',
                  height: 20,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]
      ),
    ]
);
counter++;
return child;
}

void _removeItem(int i) {
 print("====remove $i");

 print('===Removing $i');
 setState(() => _list.removeAt(i));
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('Photo'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  ),

  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(onPressed: on_Clicked, child: new 
  Icon(Icons.add),),

  body: new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: GridView(
                //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                  //childAspectRatio: 2/1,
                ),
                  children: [
                    itemBuilder: List.generate(_list.length, (index) {
                          //generating tiles with people from list
                          return _newItem(index);
                        },
                  ]
                  return Column(

                  )
                  ),
              )
          )
        ],
      ),
  ),
);
}


}
```

Please help how I add a new Column after the end of the loop on that column i add onTap property where i add append functionality to add new column when click.

Here is the code of the new column with add icon

```
InkWell(
    onTap: (){},
        child: Column(
              children: [
                Stack(
                    children: const [
                      Card(
                        elevation: 0,
                        color: Color(0xff8f9df2),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xff8f9df2),
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                        ),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          //width: 300,
                          height: 100,
                          child: Center(child:
                          Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 80.0,
                          ),

                          ),
                        ),

                      )
                    ]
                ),
            ]
         ),
    )
```

Comment: You can add extra  object to  _list   like if you have 2 items in list then add extra to that list which is dummy  or you can specify its value like isDummy to true. so , you can check while looping and that time you can check if its dummy then show that extra UI

Comment: like in void initState after _list.add(child); I add new Column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend item-count (item Length) by one and use last index to show add widget.

```dart
children: List.generate(itemLength + 1,
        (index) => index == itemLength ? Text("new Item") : _newItem(index)),
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created sample demo. you can foloow this. Hope this you want this same.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class CustomObject{
  String name;
  bool isDummy;
  CustomObject(this.name , this.isDummy);
} 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyClass(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  

  @override
  State<MyClass> createState() => _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
  
     List<CustomObject> _list =[];
  
    @override
  void initState() {
   _list =[
       CustomObject('test',false),
       CustomObject('test 2',false),
       CustomObject('',true), ///this is extra item to achieve
   ];

    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body : Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.00),
          child : GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20),
            itemCount: _list.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
              return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: (!_list[index].isDummy) ?  Text(_list[index].name) :
                  Icon(Icons.add,size: 40.00,),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              );
            }),
        ),
     );
  }
}
```

Output : [image]

Let me know if any query or anything.

Comment: thank you but it complicates me because when I add anything new it breaks my add and remove functionality and also it show so many error and also breaks layout.